# Calculate percentage of dictionary values

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

```
all_brands_scores  = dict(sorted(all_brands_scores.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
print(all_brands_scores )
```

output:

> {'ADATA': 0, 'GIGABYTE': 0, 'CyberPowerPC': 0, 'Hyundai': 0,
> 'Thomson': 0, 'KANO': 1, 'Alienware': 1, 'Razer': 1, 'Google': 1,
> 'LG': 2, 'HP OMEN': 5, 'Acer': 12, 'Apple': 13, 'Microsoft': 13,
> 'MSI': 17, 'Samsung': 18, 'Dell': 24, 'ASUS': 54, 'Lenovo': 71, 'HP':
> 104}

I have this file(dic) but not as fixed values
How do I calculate the percentage of each type of laptop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum_of_values = sum(data.values())
dict(
    map(
        lambda v: 
            [
                v[0],
                str(v[1] / sum_of_values * 100) + "%"
            ],
            data.items()
        )
    )
```

Comment: thank you very mach 
but but How can I convert it to the following format x%

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the original values with their percentages:

```
total = sum(all_brands_scores.values())
for key,val in all_brands_scores.items():
    all_brands_scores[key] = round(val/total * 100, 2)
```

If you want a new dictionary of percentages:

```
perc_dict = {}
total = sum(all_brands_scores.values())
    for key,val in all_brands_scores.items():
        perc_dict[key] = round(val/total * 100, 2)
```

If you want to add the % symbol, then you will have to convert the values into string format:

```
perc_dict = {}
total = sum(all_brands_scores.values())
for key,val in all_brands_scores.items():
    perc_dict[key] = str(round(val/total * 100, 2)) + '%'
```

(Rounding off the percentages till 2 decimal places.)

Comment: but How can I convert it to the following format
 x%